# Construct an order on a field $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the field of rational numbers. Let $\mathbb{Q}^2=\{(a,b):a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ and define addition and multiplication as follows:
$$
(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)\\
(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+2bd, ad+bc)
$$
Then $(\mathbb{Q}^2, +, \cdot)$ is a field, and $(0,0)$ is its zero element while $(1,0)$ is its unit element. The inverse of $(a,b)$ is $(\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2},-\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2})$. I'm asked to construct an order on it such that it becomes an ordered field, namely invariant under addition and multiplication with a positive element.

What I know is $(1,0)>(0,0)$, so $(n,0)>(0,0)$ for any natural number $n$. I don't quite know how to proceed. Is there any rules to follow to construct an order on a field?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I assume that you mean $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ (rather than $(a+b,c+d)$ as currently written).

Comment: @TobyBartels Sorry I have corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any general rules, but in this case your field is actually (isomorphic to) a sub-field of $\mathbb{R}$. If you calculate what $$(0,1) \cdot (0,1)$$ is it may suggest how to map your field into $\mathbb{R}$. Then you can "pull back" the order on $\mathbb{R}$ onto your field.

BTW, @Toby's observation that such an order is not unique supports the idea that there are not general rules. If there were a set of rules they would likely lead to a unique answer, but we can see that there isn't a unique answer. And while we're talking more generally it's also worth noting that sometimes there is no such order, e.g. there never is for any finite field.

---

Follow up: If my comments about uniqueness don't make sense to you right now feel free to ignore them; they're just there to give a wider more general view.

Yes, that's the isomorphism I was thinking of. Because $$(1,0) \cdot (a,b) = (a,b)$$ for any $(a,b)$ we can see that $(1,0)$ acts like $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, and because $$(0,1)^2 = (0,1)\cdot(0,1) = (2,0)$$ we can see that $(0,1)$ acts like $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ (or like $-\sqrt{2}$ if you prefer - you can choose either but then must stick with it,)

So it makes sense to define $\phi : \mathbb{Q}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\phi( (a,b) ) = a+b\sqrt{2}$. Now you must explicitly show that $$ \phi((a,b)+(c,d)) = \phi((a,b)) + \phi((c,d))$$ and $$ \phi((a,b)\cdot(c,d)) = \phi((a,b)) \cdot \phi((c,d))$$ (As you write out the proof for multiplication you might see why we had to choose $\pm\sqrt{2}$ for $(0,1)$.

After you've done that you can "pull back" the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, which means you define that "$(a,b) \lt_{\mathbb{Q}^2} (c,d) \iff \phi((a,b)) \lt_\mathbb{R} \phi((c,d))$", where the $\lt_\mathbb{R}$ on the right-hand side is the usual order on $\mathbb{R}$. You should then be able to show that  $\lt_{\mathbb{Q}^2}$ is invariant under addition and multiplication by using the invariance of $\lt_\mathbb{R}$. Note that this is something that you have to write out explictly; it's not enough to observe it. If you're just getting started in abstract algebra you might find this a little hard but really you're just applying $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ and "pushing symbols around".

Notice that this method assumes the existence of both $\mathbb{R}$ and its invariant ordering $\lt_\mathbb{R}$ (and also the existence of $\sqrt{2})$. Since this will make the problem much easier I'd go ahead and assume we know they exist. If we were not allowed to assume them we'd have to find a way to express "$a+b\sqrt{2} \lt c+d\sqrt{2}$" without using the concept of $\sqrt{2}$, which gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Right, this is not the only answer (no general rules, as you said), but it's probably the simplest answer.  (Actually, even this gives two answers, as there are two choices for the real number to use as $(0,1)$, one positive and one negative.)

Comment: @TobyBartels, oh, that's a great observation, and really highlights the fact that such an order is not unique. If I were writing this up for class I'd choose the less obvious.one just to be contrary.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the isomorphism you suggest $(a,b) \to a+b\sqrt{2}$? I'm not so familiar with abstract algebra though. I'm not sure whether I get your ideas.

Comment: @EdwardWang - I extended my answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 1):

The quick and easy answer is to notice that this field is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}]$ by sending $(a,b)$ to $a+b\sqrt 2$, so $(a,b)<(c,d)$ if $a+b\sqrt 2<c+d\sqrt 2$.

Comment: but the question remains to know if $(a-c)^2<2(b-d)^2$ follows the same order.